# What limits are there for an NFL teams reserves list?

Tags: american-football, nfl, finances

There is a maximum to the number of players that are allowed on the active roster of a team in the NFL, but is there any limit to the number of players who may be placed on a teams reserve list (assuming they fit the qualifying criteria)?

Do players on the reserves list always count against a teams cap space, or are there any cases where they do not?